# Using inheritance in Java with array-List

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

1. Main Class
2. Game class
3. Player class - parent class
4. PlayerType class - child class

I want to set attributes of both player - number of games played,games won,Player name and playertype - stores the type of player - dummy or computer. Earlier I was calling `Player()` in Game class, where it sets the default values to Player's attributes. Main class creates array-List of type player. However, now with requirement of type of player too, I am confused. How to implement this?

1) Main Class

```
static ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>(); //Array-List is created of type Player.
```

2) Game Class

```
Game()
{
    Player player1 = new Player();
    Player player2 = new Player();
}
```

3) Player Class

```
Player()
{
   //some attributes
}
```

4) PlayerType extends Player

```
//some attributes

PlayerType()
{
   //initialize attributes.
}
```

I want Game class to initialize all the attributes of player. In addition to this, PlayerType has some getters,setters and functions, and so does Player. Can I use those by creating their respective objects, and calling these functions?

Comment: what you "want" is tutorial, StackOverflow is not for you!!

Comment: @Batty - yes I know. However, I am confused how array-List will work over here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:-

```
static ArrayList<? extends Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

Comment: static ArrayList<PlayerType> players = new ArrayList<PlayerType>();

Comment: PlayerType(){ super() }

Comment: He's showing you how to declare ArrayList so that it will only accept objects that are either Player's or children that inherit from Player.